# Openpyxl: Importing values - processing - writing the results on excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

Hello I am trying to import a range of values from excel to python do some calculations and writing them on the same excel spreadsheet in column C2 but I have a problem on finding a code to write them. Can anyone help?

This is the code I am using:

```
import openpyxl
import numpy
import math

c = 200

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('SPLtest.xlsx')
turbine_data = wb.get_sheet_by_name('TurbinedataV')
SPLvalues = wb.get_sheet_by_name('SPLvalues')

for row in range (2, SPLvalues.max_row + 1):
    f = SPLvalues['A' + str(row)].value

for row in range (2, SPLvalues.max_row + 1):
    L_w = SPLvalues['B' + str(row)].value

NSA_SPL = L_w + f + c*f

SPLvalues = wb.active
for rowNum in range (2,SPLvalues.max_row):
SPLvalues.cell(row=rowNum, column=3).value = SPLvalues
```

[image: Excel structure]

Comment: Use `pandas` http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15/10min.html

Comment: Your loops will only ever give you one value and your last loop tries to assign a whole worksheet to a single cell.